# Does Stack Exchange track the edit history of a user's `Location` field?

Tags: support, data-explorer, schema

If I want to compare how many posts per location are asked by users over a period of N years, I would want to know how many users have changed locations during the period that I want to query.

Is this possible? It doesn't appear to be based on the schema (I'm looking at the Stack Exchange Data Explorer explicitly, but I am interested in knowing about the other sites as well) - I don't think I can see the edit history of the user table. I guess this makes sense for privacy reasons?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: if you wanted to measure, for example, code questions per region over time. you would want to know when a user moved countries - some of their questions would be from the US (if they lived there initially). Then if they moved to South Africa, the rest of their questions would be from South Africa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we don't. We don't even record an event in the user's history that the field changed *at all* - we only log events when a user changes their profile picture, display name, or about me as far as public information goes, and that history is only available to moderators.